# Line detection with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to detect the presence of lines from a picture of a geometrical drawing. For example, there is a triangle, and I'm looking for the bisector of one of its angles. So I know exactly where and how long the line should be.

My approach so far is to detect all the lines with the Hough transform function and look for my line among those. However, this is rather slow and conceptually not very nice. Indeed, since I know the two extremities of the segment I'm looking for, it seems more natural to directly look for at this very place.

To do this, my first intuition was to use the result of Canny and loop through each pixel that should contain a line. Before I implement this, I was wondering if something similar already existed or if someone more expert in CV would recommend another approach. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227074/horizontal-line-detection-with-opencv) but I'm looking for lines, not contour, so not sure this would work...

Answer (score 1):

The Canny idea might work quite well. Since you were looking for other ideas, you might also consider trying corner detection. Assuming the geomerical shape is segmented you might try either the classic [Harris corners](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html) or you might try some of the newer [feature detectors](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html) like SURF, SIFT, FAST, etc. You may have to adjust the parameter sensitivities of these detectors in order to isolate the corners, but that might allow you to compute the lines based on a set of points. Also, a combination of Canny edge detection and feature detection might be more robust as well.

Just a thought :) Hope it helps!