# Detecting location of translucent black rectangluar area in image matrix Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

Say I have an image like this:

[image]

I want the **location of the start and end points of the black strip in the image matrix**.

I have tried several method like [horizontal line detection in Python OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227074/horizontal-line-detection-with-opencv) and have come up with following code that gets me the lines highlighted:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

img = cv2.imread('caption.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1,np.pi/180,350);
for line in lines[0]:
    pt1 = (line[0],line[1])
    pt2 = (line[2],line[3])
    cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255))



gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

print img.shape

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,350)

for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    if int(b) == 1: #only horizontal lines with cos theta(theta = 0) = 1
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow('edges', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]

If I try `print x1, y1, x2, y2` i get

> -1000 781 999 782
>   -1000 712 999 713

So these obviously are not the location points in the image matrix like x is negative.

**What is the location of the start and endpoints of these lines in the image matrix?** I need to perform some point operation on the pixels in that area and hence need the start and endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines will always return -1000 + the original point

```
x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
```

As you only get into this loop if `int(b) == 1:`

Which means that you need to print the x0 directly, since the above lines will always be `(x0 + (-1000))`, **in this case x0 is 0 since it starts from the left of the image.**

Comment: What about y? I mean I have x0 and y0 for the first line what about the second? What are the starting points of the second line?

Comment: Also, how do I access this in the matrix? It is surely not at img[x0] since x0 is 0 and it is the first row