# Detect horizontal white lines from image and get their coordinates with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

My goal is separate web pages into parts (header, contacts, footer,...) with OpenCV Python. I converted the image of the web page to grayscale and used Canny. Here's the result:

[image: Original Image to Grayscale + Canny Result]

As you can see, the border of the parts are very clear with the human eyes to detect, and I think this problem is little for OpenCV, but I can't figure out how to export each part into a separate file (or at least get the lines' coordinates).

Here's my current code for Grayscale + Canny

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img   = cv2.imread("image.png",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 5, 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Hough lines and check for `slope = 0`. You will find [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/lhMXDqQHf9gA) very helpful and interesting.

Comment: If it helps, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted so that it can help others in the future. @ĐiềnBáQuan

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to look at the statistics along the image's rows.
For instance, is you look at the `mean` intensity along the rows, boundary rows has `mean` close to 1.0.

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm so stupid but how can I get these "statistics"? :)

Comment: @ĐiềnBáQuan the mean->also known as the average. in other words add all the pixels on a row, divided by the width (number of pixels in a row) and you get a value between 0-255 (or 0-1.0 if you a have floats or double), the white horizontal lines should have a value close to 255 (or 1.0) since most of the values will be white

Comment: Thank you very much! I have succeeded my goal. :)

Comment: @ĐiềnBáQuan please do not use the term "stupid" here: you are doing nice image processing work. you are definitely **NOT** stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some ways to get the white lines:

- [Hough lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7228823/365102)
- [Morphology](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html)

OpenCV's `HoughLines` and `HoughLinesP` are good starting points.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Researching those topics :)