# Detection and Cleaning of Strike-out Texts on Handwriting

Tags: orc, google-ai-platform, handwriting-recognition

I have images where the text is strike-out and replace by next words. Sometimes it's just one line that gets struck out. Other times, multiple lines are.

[image]

I expected output should be like this. remove strike-out words and replace it by the the next word.
[image]
and then i will send that line to google AI to get the text
[image]

I'm using Google AI Vision. How i can detect and clean that Strike-out Texts before sending to Google vision.

(Or maybe after receive a response from google)

I tried using google AI api. It can pass the Strike-out Texts however it's left a space on my document
Here is the paper related: https://cdn.iiit.ac.in/cdn/cvit.iiit.ac.in/SSDA/slides/Jaipur%20Strike_out_BBChaudhuri.pdf

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your requirements? Specifically, which text do you need to remove before sending the image to the Cloud Vision API? Additionally, could you provide a sample output of the desired result?

Comment: Hi Kiran Mathew. I have update my simple output and requirement. I also found a paper that may related to this work.

Comment: Could you take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669589/)?

Comment: Hi, you stated that you were able to remove the strikeout text but it just left a blank space in the document. How did you manage to do that with Google vision AI?